# Oracle SQL - date comparison does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to retrieve all records with DATETIME SCHEDFINISH field with value TODAY or TOMORROW (regardless of TIME part, DATE part is just important)

I tried this:

```
select schedfinish from plans
where 
TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')+1<= TO_DATE(SCHEDFINISH,'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

but it returns me for SCHEDFINISH column values and 31.10.2013; 28.2.2014, 31.1.2015 so the results are totally incorrect. 
I would like to use this CURRENT_DATE syntax if possible but why does it not work?

If I try just for TODAY then it works:

```
 TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')= TO_DATE(SCHEDFINISH,'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

but I need today and tomorrow.

Thanks

Comment: Are current_date an schedfinish strings?  If not, why are you running a to_date funtions with a mask?

Comment: CURRENT_DATE is oracle variable if I understand correctly. SHCEDFINISH is DATETIME field in DB

Comment: `TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')` does not make *any* sense. `to_date()` converts a **varchar** to a date. But `current_date` is already a `DATE`. So using that function first implicitely converts a date to a varchar just to convert it back to a `date` and probably wrong as well if your NLS settings define a different date format than `YYYY/MM/DD`. The same goes for the column `SCHEDFINISH` if that is defined as `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`)

Comment: I bet if you do `select TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')+1 from plans` you get the year 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming schedfinish is a date datatype, you can do this:

```
where schedfinish >= trunc(current_date)
and schedfinish < trunc(current_date + 2)
```

Comment: thank you it seems it works. Just one small question if I wanted just for TODAY why does this don't work: (schedfinish = trunc(sysdate))

Comment: I accepted you answer can you just please tell me if I wanted rows only for today why this does not work:schedfinish = trunc(current_date)

Comment: can you please answer me or should I open new question? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to answer that without seeing values of schedfinish.  However, if these values contain any time element whatsoever, they will not equal the results of the trunc function because those results will have all zeros in the time portion.  StevieG's answer shows you one method of using trunc on both fields to get records for today only, however, using functions like that slows down your query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of `TO_DATE`, if you run this:

```
SELECT 
  TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')+1 currentdate, 
  TO_DATE(SCHEDFINISH,'YYYY/MM/DD') myscheddate,
  SCHEDFINISH
FROM plans
WHERE TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')+1<= TO_DATE(SCHEDFINISH,'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

..you'll see the problem. When using `TO_DATE`, the format string you supply is telling the database the format that the first parameter is in. However, `CURRENT_DATE` and (I suspect) `SCHEDFINISH` are not in `YYYY/MM/DD` format, so the result of the conversion is wrong.

Given that they are both dates anyway, you don't need to do any casting `TO_DATE` you can just do:

```
SELECT SCHEDFINISH
FROM plans
WHERE SCHEDFINISH >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
AND SCHEDFINISH < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE+2);
```

...the `TRUNC` keyword truncates your date field (basically sets the time portion to 00:00:00), which is what I think you were trying to do with the cast. So if you wanted to get records for today, you would do:

```
SELECT SCHEDFINISH
FROM plans
WHERE TRUNC(SCHEDFINISH) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: this is not so good because as result I also receive 31.1.2015 but I wish only today and tomorrow

Comment: @jajaaaa - its the same answer as Dan gave above, but you said that worked?